Finding the Minimum Distance Between a Circle and a Line in 3D Space
In 3D space, I want to find a point Pc on a given circle and a point Pl on a given line such that the distance between Pc and Pl is minimized. How can I calculate these points?
I have tried finding the closest point on the line to the center of the circle, but this point is not the closest to the circle's border in most cases.

When u say circle u refer to a sphere? or is a circle with its own direction?

a circle defined by its center, radius, and normal vector.

Is your line infinite? Or is it a line segment?

Its an infinite line

As it is, this is a maths question so off topic here. I would start by parameterizing points on the line and circle with parameters s,t say, then work out a formula for the distance between the two points D(s,t) and then try to solve the simultaneous partial differential equations dD/ds = 0 and dD/dt = 0.

I feel that this question is slightly off-topic on StackOverflow (programming) as it's mostly a mathematics / geometry related question. Basically it breaks down into two subproblems: 1. Finding an expression for the distance to the closest point on a circle relative to a point in 3D space. 2. Find the point along a line in 3D space for which that distance is minimal.

@SimonGoater you don't even have to solve a PDE problem. Finding the distance to the closest point on a circle (basically just Pythagoras to account for the out-of-plane component) and then a minimization problem of that distance for points on a line.

@datenwolf Yeah, good point. That would be easier. The nearest point on the circle you can get by projecting the line between the circle centre and the point on the line onto the circle's plane, then you only need to find dD/ds = 0.

I think there's the possibility that this problem has a closed form solution. I believe the sought line has to be perpendicular to L as well as C (the circle). I haven't fully considered this though.

Maybe its not the best performance code but for the closest point in line to circle/point (its the same in for this case)
//a,b are points of line
//c is center of circle or point in space
float3 ClosestPointInLine(float3 a, float3 b, float3 c){
    float3 o1 = b-a;
    float3 o2 = c-a;
    float o3 = dot(o1,o2);
    float o4 = distance(a,b);
    float t = o3/(o4*o4);
    float tc = min(1,max(t,0));
    return a + o1 * tc;
}

The closest point in circle to line its quite ambiguous and harder to find.
Think if the line is parallel to the circle then there are infinite points to the same distance.
EDIT:
Even if its ambiguos we can calculate it with the closest point of the line to circle or Disk
ProjectPointOnPlane(float3 pos, float3 normal, float3 p){
    float3 moved = p-pos;
    float dist = dot(moved,normal);
    return p-(normal*dist);
}

ClosestPointToDisk(float3 diskPos, float3 diskNormal, float radius, float3 point){
    float3 planePoint = ProjectPointOnPlane(diskPos, diskNormal,point);
    float3 dir = diskPos - planePoint;
    if(dir.magnitude < radius){
        return planePoint;
    }
    
    return dir.normalized * radius + diskPos;
}

ClosestPointToCircle(float3 circlePos, float3 circleNormal, float radius, float3 point){
    float3 planePoint = ProjectPointOnPlane(circlePos, circleNormal,point);
    float3 dir = circlePos - planePoint;
    return dir.normalized * radius + diskPos;
}

ClosestPointLineToDisk(Disk d, Line l){
    float3 nearPoint = ClosestPointInLine(l.start, l.end, d.position);
    return ClosestPointToDisk(d.position, d.normal, d.radius, nearPoint);
}

ClosestPointLineToCircle(Circle c, Line l){
    float3 nearPoint = ClosestPointInLine(l.start, l.end, c.position);
    return ClosestPointToCircle(c.position, c.normal, c.radius, nearPoint);
}


These two last functions will give you one and only one point.

you defined the circle purely by its center. you still need to incorporate its normal/plane and radius.

Like i said if you have a line defined as parallel to the disk then u cant calculate the closest point in the circle to the line.
If you reffer only to the closest point in circle border then u would have two point when its parallel

I believe you're missing the issue. you didn't respond to my point. your response is to a point I didn't make.

I understand the issue but the thing is that you can make the closest point to the entire disk or even only the outside to ANOTHER POINT but not to a line because in the case of being parallel you can have either 2 or infinite solutions. In case you need it i can make the closest point to disk and to circle to a point and use de closest point to the other function i already wrote

the existence of corner cases (multiple solutions) is irrelevant to your answer. your answer does not provide a correct solution in the usual case. it doesn't even involve the circle's radius, so it can't possibly be correct. that is the issue here. I'm not arguing with you. I'm just pointing out this answer is wrong to anyone who reads this. they can make up their own minds from the arguments.

check the edit to see if it works for you
